# Do the $4$ Pythagorean means divide into two algebraic dualities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I’m looking to understand the relationship between rectangular product & mean square operations -- or, equivalently, between their root operations, the geometric & quadratic means.  Here’s the problem:

Suppose we define an isomorphic mapping **CR(a,b)** to re-describe argument real pair **a,b** into their conjugate roots -- i.e.,
$$CR(a,b) = \left( \sqrt a+\sqrt b, \sqrt a-\sqrt b \right)$$

With the function arguments so ‘re-described’, **subtraction becomes re-describable as a product, and addition as a mean square**:

$$
\begin{split}
\text{Diff}(a,b)
  = a - b
 &= \left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b\right)\left(\sqrt a-\sqrt b\right)
  = \text{Prod}(CR(a,b)) \\
\text{Sum}(a,b)
  = a + b
 &= \frac{\left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b\right)^2+\left(\sqrt a-\sqrt b\right)^2}{2}
  = \text{MeanSq}(CR(a,b))
\end{split}
$$

So subtracting a pair of real numbers is always just **multiplying** their conjugate square roots, and summing them likewise just **mean-squaring** those same conjugate square roots.  **7** is thus not just the difference of **16 and 9**, but the product of their conjugate square roots **(4+3)(4-3)**; likewise, **25** is not just their sum, but the mean-square of those conjugate square roots **(49+1)/2**.

**But the sum & difference operations on the left-side of the above equations are *inverse* operations to one another -- by definition, even.  Can the corresponding right-sides of the above equations, multiplying & mean-squaring, be similarly understood as inverse operations of each other??**

Since those latter operations, rectangular product & mean-square, are 2-degree area-functions, perhaps the question is best addressed to their 1-degree linear counterparts (i.e., their own square roots), in which case we ask then after the relationship between **geometric mean & quadratic mean**.  And this appears to offer some promise, since among the four Pythagorean means, the other two -- arithmetic & harmonic means -- are, obviously, multiplicative “duals” of one another:

$$
\begin{split}
HM(a,b) &= {1 \over AM(\frac1a,\frac1b)} \\
AM(a,b) &= {1 \over HM(\frac1a,\frac1b)}
\end{split}
$$

…and in that sense they are in "inverse" relationship, with the geometric mean that falls between them being multiplicatively **self-**dual, $GM(a,b)= {1 \over GM(1/a,1/b)}$.

But can all four Pythagorean means then really be so neatly paired off that the quadratic mean **QM** be in some way “dual with” or "inverse to" **GM**?  The following diagram in Wikipedia, which relates them as a “central secant” (my term for it) vs. a tangent, looks promising in this regard, but I myself am not quite seeing what the **inversion** would then be, conceptually:

> [image: Pythagorean means visualized] *

---

Please feel free to suggest other **tags** appropriate to this question.  I am, frankly, not quite sure under what math subfields it falls.

- Image here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#/media/File:QM_AM_GM_HM_inequality_visual_proof.svg
  ( The diagram is drawn from these larger articles:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means#Inequalities_among_means
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Relationship_to_other_statistics )

Comment: Interesting but I do not subscribe to your use of the word 'inverse" when you say that $a-b$ is the *inverse operation* of $a+b$...

Comment: @Jean Marie
Well, surely you would at least grant that, from center point a, adding -b is the inverse operation on a of adding +b?  -b is, after all, the additive inverse of b.

Comment: Yes, I agree of course with that. Besides, there is also an important mean (on which I have worked) which isn't enough cited : the [logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean)

Comment: Oh, my that is a very interesting mean I did not know about.  Thank you for sharing!  The identities listed in subsection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean#Connection_to_other_means make it a ripe topic for insight.